# OpenLDAP: MemberOf & Java

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

I'm using OpenLDAP 2.4 for user authentication. To assign roles I added users to groups using the member attribute. Because some applications need a memberOf information I enabled the memberOf overlay (which is working as expected).

So in fact I can get the memberOf property using ldapsearch but the problem is that an application can't retrieve this information because the memberOf property is no real attribute. This application is using the java functions:

- search (javax.naming.directory.dircontext)
- getAttribute (javax.naming.directory.searchresult)

So my question is if there's a way to make this memberOf property "visible" as an real attribute or if there's an other java function which can retrieve this memberOf property.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Okay I found it out on my own. I just have to define the operational attribute (in this case "memberOf") I want to retrieve as a parameter for the getAttribute() function. That's it :)

Comment: Using * and + together will give you all regular and operational attributes.

Comment: You 'found it out on your own' five days after Terry told you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory server information model does not have properties, it has attributes. The `memberOf` attribute must be requested, that is, it must be included in the requested attribute list that is part of the search request. For more information about search requests and ldapsearch see "[Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)".

Comment: Yes, but still the memberOf is not a normal but a so called operational attribute as the openldap docu says and that's the reason why it's not listed when u request all attributes for example.
It's not that I have a problem using ldapsearch (when using it I can retrieve all the memberOf information I need). The problem is that the java function search does not find the memberOf operational attribute even though ldapsearch does. My question is if I can somehow manage it that even this java function will find the memberOf

Comment: @Flek you've just repeated what Terry told you, and then ignored it. If you want an operational attribute returned by a search, you have to name it explicitly.